# Concatenating two geodataframes needs CRS Adjustment

Tags: coordinate-system, geopandas, geodataframe, valueerror

I have two geodataframes which I would like to concatenate. I have tried this:

```
test=gpd.GeoDataFrame( pd.concat( [gdf1, gdf2], ignore_index=True) )
```

where `print(gdf1.columns)` and `print(gdf2.columns)` both give

```
Index(['ville', 'objectid', 'geometry', 'area_km2'], dtype='object')
```

and where `print(gdf1.geometry.crs)`  and `print(gdf2.geometry.crs)` both give `+init=epsg:4326 +type=crs`

yet i am getting this error:

> ValueError: Cannot determine common CRS for concatenation inputs, got
> ['WGS 84', 'WGS 84']. Use `to_crs()` to transform geometries to the
> same CRS before merging.
>
> Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text
> editor. Adjust cell output settings...

How can this be possible when both CRS are on 4326 (GPS)

Any idea?

Comment: It is false  but  `print(gd1.crs)` and
`print(gdf2.crs)`  both give 4326

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try resetting the crs's to make sure they are the same:

```
gdf1 = gdf1.to_crs("epsg:4326")
gdf2 = gdf2.to_crs("epsg:4326")
```

then concat